# How to print the data of a C structure in Windbg

Tags: c, windows, debugging, windbg

In the windows debugger I am trying to print out the data passed to a c function.  I am interested in the data passed into System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_step+0x63.

```
0:071> kv 20
Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00000000`11b82e28 00000642`ff864776 : 00000000`12f6f450 00000000`0092dcd8 00000000`11b83488 00000000`11b83480 : ntdll!NtGetContextThread+0xa
00000000`11b82e30 00000000`12f6f450 : 00000000`0092dcd8 00000000`11b83488 00000000`11b83480 00000000`11b83470 : <Unloaded_mscordacwks.dll>+0x154776
00000000`11b82e38 00000000`0092dcd8 : 00000000`11b83488 00000000`11b83480 00000000`11b83470 00000000`77ee2ae9 : 0x12f6f450
00000000`11b82e40 00000000`11b83488 : 00000000`11b83480 00000000`11b83470 00000000`77ee2ae9 00000000`12c1a970 : 0x92dcd8
00000000`11b82e48 00000000`11b83480 : 00000000`11b83470 00000000`77ee2ae9 00000000`12c1a970 00000000`ffffffff : 0x11b83488
00000000`11b82e50 00000000`11b83470 : 00000000`77ee2ae9 00000000`12c1a970 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`00920be8 : 0x11b83480
00000000`11b82e58 00000000`77ee2ae9 : 00000000`12c1a970 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`00920be8 00000000`00000000 : 0x11b83470
00000000`11b82e60 00000000`77ecff89 : 00000000`00920000 00000000`00920090 00000000`00920090 00000642`ff710000 : ntdll!RtlDeleteCriticalSection+0x11c
00000000`11b82e90 00000000`77d53f8a : 00000000`1279ba00 00000000`13129d30 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlDestroyHeap+0x2b1
00000000`11b82f00 00000000`77ef7708 : 00000642`ff89b080 00000000`000000b0 00000000`1279ba0d 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!HeapDestroy+0xa
00000000`11b82f30 00000000`1279ba58 : 00000000`1279ba0f 00000642`ff710000 00000642`001bd000 00000000`00000001 : ntdll!LdrLockLoaderLock+0x15f
00000000`11b82f90 00000000`1279ba0f : 00000642`ff710000 00000642`001bd000 00000000`00000001 00000000`11b83488 : 0x1279ba58
00000000`11b82f98 00000642`ff710000 : 00000642`001bd000 00000000`00000001 00000000`11b83488 00000000`11b83480 : 0x1279ba0f
00000000`11b82fa0 00000642`001bd000 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`11b83488 00000000`11b83480 00000000`11b83470 : <Unloaded_mscordacwks.dll>
00000000`11b82fa8 00000000`00000001 : 00000000`11b83488 00000000`11b83480 00000000`11b83470 00000000`77eee1e5 : 0x642`001bd000
00000000`11b82fb0 00000000`11b83488 : 00000000`11b83480 00000000`11b83470 00000000`77eee1e5 00000000`1279ba10 : 0x1
00000000`11b82fb8 00000000`11b83480 : 00000000`11b83470 00000000`77eee1e5 00000000`1279ba10 00000000`11b83028 : 0x11b83488
00000000`11b82fc0 00000000`11b83470 : 00000000`77eee1e5 00000000`1279ba10 00000000`11b83028 00000000`00000000 : 0x11b83480
00000000`11b82fc8 00000000`77eee1e5 : 00000000`1279ba10 00000000`11b83028 00000000`00000000 00000000`11b83478 : 0x11b83470
00000000`11b82fd0 00000000`77d6d721 : 00000642`ff710000 00000000`03651690 00000000`11b834a0 00000642`ff710000 : ntdll!LdrUnloadDll+0x8ad
00000000`11b83150 000007ff`7252f5f3 : 00000000`03651690 00000000`03651690 00000000`03651690 00000642`ff710000 : kernel32!FreeLibrary+0x6b
00000000`11b83180 000007ff`7252cf60 : 00000000`11b83da0 00000642`82e30018 00000000`00002900 00000000`00000000 : dbghelp!NtWin32LiveSystemProvider::EnumFunctionTables+0x223
00000000`11b83430 000007ff`7252a6c9 : 00000000`123d8660 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000002 ffffffff`ffffffff : dbghelp!GenGetProcessInfo+0x860
00000000`11b83d30 000007ff`7252a89c : 00000000`00000002 00000001`5fff1fe0 00000000`00000000 00000000`0364f3b0 : dbghelp!MiniDumpProvideDump+0x639
00000000`11b83f30 00000000`0bd73939 : 00000000`11b84050 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000000 00000000`0c040be0 : dbghelp!MiniDumpWriteDump+0x13c
00000000`11b84000 00000000`0bd81e59 : 00000000`00000002 00000000`11b854f0 00000000`11b8b52c 00000000`0bdd0110 : System_Data_SQLite!CreateMinidumpHook+0x119 [c:\dev\sqlite\sqlite.interop\src\win\interop.c @ 117]
00000000`11b84490 00000000`0bd75483 : 00000000`00000002 00000000`0be029f0 00000000`000048b1 00000000`00000000 : System_Data_SQLite!_VCrtDbgReportW+0x7a9 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\dbgrptt.c @ 589]
00000000`11b8c590 00000000`0bd7541d : 00000642`00000002 00000000`0be029f0 00000000`000048b1 00000000`00000000 : System_Data_SQLite!_CrtDbgReportWV+0x43 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\dbgrpt.c @ 242]
00000000`11b8c5d0 00000000`0bc85b12 : 00000000`00000002 00000000`0be029f0 00000000`000048b1 00000000`00000000 : System_Data_SQLite!_CrtDbgReportW+0x4d [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\dbgrpt.c @ 258]
00000000`11b8c620 00000000`0bc8515c : 00000000`2cc67ca0 00000642`7f4ce081 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : System_Data_SQLite!winMutexEnter+0xa2 [c:\dev\sqlite\sqlite.interop\src\core\sqlite3.c @ 18609]
00000000`11b8c670 00000000`0bcb3203 : 00000000`2cc67ca0 00000642`7f4ce0e4 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_mutex_enter+0x1c [c:\dev\sqlite\sqlite.interop\src\core\sqlite3.c @ 17474]
00000000`11b8c6a0 00000642`7f6005f7 : 00000001`c14e4100 00000000`a4cc7610 00000001`c61d3750 00000642`782ea561 : System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_step+0x63 [c:\dev\sqlite\sqlite.interop\src\core\sqlite3.c @ 64122]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either enter:

```
kP
```

which will dump the parameters for each call formatted

or

```
dt System_Data_SQLite!<type> // replace <type> with whatever you are interested in
```

see this for more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2006/03/22/558329.aspx and here: http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html#17_variables

Comment: Ok, kp gives me this:


00000000`11b8c6a0 00000642`7f6005f7 System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_step(struct sqlite3_stmt * pStmt = 0x00000001`c14e4100)+0x63 [c:\dev\sqlite\sqlite.interop\src\core\sqlite3.c @ 64122]

now I just need to print out the struct sqlite3_stmt * pStmt = 0x00000001`c14e4100

Comment: does `dt 0x00000001`c14e4100 System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_stmt` work?

Comment: dt 0x00000001c14e4100 System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_stmt
Symbol System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_stmt not found.

I switched to the right frame, .frame 1f

then did dt System_Data_SQLite!sqlite3_step

sqlite3_stmt* pStmt = 00000001`c14e4100 )

And  dt pStmt
Local var @ 0x11b8c710 Type sqlite3_stmt*

None of these are giving me the contents of that struct!

Comment: :071> dv
          pStmt = 0x00000001`c14e4100
            rc2 = 0
            cnt = 0
             rc = 0
              v = 0x00000001`c14e4100
             db = 0x00000000`2f87aae0

dt v gives the the contents of v, but dt pStmt only gives me the address.

Comment: 0:071> dt pStmt -v
Local var [AddrFlags d0  AddrOff 0000000000000070  Reg/Val rsp (7)] @ 0x11b8c710 Type sqlite3_stmt*
0x00000001`c14e4100 struct sqlite3_stmt, 0 elements, 0x0 bytes